# How to narrow the result from Nominatim with only cities and countries, no additional areas with the same name?

Tags: openstreetmap, polygon, nominatim

I'm trying to get WKT or GeoJson polygons of cities and countries from Nominatim (for example, Paris and France). I send a `GET` request but it returns me several results named "Paris" or "France". How may I narrow results only to a capital and a country. Here's my request url:

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/fr/paris?format=json&polygon_geojson=1
```

And I get an array of 10 objects where only one is the capital:

```
class: "boundary", type: "administrative".
```

The rest are:

```
class: "place", type: "isolated_dwelling"
class: "place", type: "hamlet",
class: "place", type: "neighbourhood"
and so on...
```

How to select only the desired city and only the desired country ignoring rest of results with the same name?

Comment: duplicate question: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/27915/how-to-narrow-the-result-from-nominatim-with-only-cities-and-countries-no-additional-areas

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a situation that the user asked on the OSM site, and got an answer there: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/27915/how-to-narrow-the-result-from-nominatim-with-only-cities-and-countries-no-additional-areas

Comment: I don't think that cross posting to a third party site, should make this question off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

As you seem to try to getting **bulk data**, you are encouraged to append the `email=...` param to avoid beein blocked.
You can use [various place=* tags](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Special_Phrases/EN) to prefilter your results or even limit your result.

As **Nominatim isn't build as a data provider**, you might use to get the boundary polygons here:
http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/france.html
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WIWOSM